# Is there a formal term for functions that have static state across executions?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, variable-binding, imperative-programming, design-patterns

Two examples, one in PHP:

```
function adder($i){
  static $a = 0; 
  $a += $i; 
  return $a;
}
```

A similar effect can be achieved with closures in javascript:

```
var adder = (function(){ 
  var a = 0; 
  return function(i){ 
    a += i;
    return a;
  } 
})();
```

In javascript I've really just created an object. Implementation details not withstanding, does stateful-functions have a formal name?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange. Please read
http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour, if you have not yet done so. --- Asking for terminology is appropriate, and you did it well, but thanks for reminding me to change your tag.

Comment: @babou I did thank you, and I wasn't entirely clear on whether asking for terminology was appropriate so I also asked in chat.

Comment: Not that I know of but I could be wrong. That said though there is a term for a function that captures a value and that is called a "closure".

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of, but "stateful function" is reasonably descriptive.  In informal conversation, that's what I'd use, as long as I suspect the audience will understand what I mean.  In formal writing, I might still use the same phrase but also provide a careful definition of what I meant by that phrase.  Really, that's a large part of what "formal" writing is about: it's about being precise about what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

In the realm of functional programing, functions that give the same result when called with the same arguments are usually called *pure*.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) explicitly adds the condition that mutable variables should not be modified by the function call, though presumably they mean mutable variables **that can be observed outside of the function scope** which shouldn't be the case for the variable `a` in your adder function (in a [sane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope) language).

This would make the result of `adder` an *impure* function, though that might have some negative connotation.